# Elasticsearch crashes when updated data path

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch setup works fine with default configurations.
  But when updated its path.data setting from elasticsearch.yml file it crashes with below error

```
[2015-11-19 12:39:56,194][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/home/hadoop/bigdata/data/elasticsearch)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:197)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:100)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:181)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/hadoop/bigdata/data
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:308)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:702)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:218)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:195)
        ... 6 more
```

I have copied elasticsearch directory from /var/lib location with preserved mode. But no success.
Can anybody please help me to come out of this error

Thanks,
Sanjay Bhosale

Comment: Are you sure that the user with which the `elasticsearch` process is launched has access to the `/home/hadoop/bigdata/data/elasticsearch` folder ?

Comment: yes since i have copied same directory with all permission and user settings.

Comment: We can still see that there is an Access denied to the folder `/home/hadoop/bigdata/data`. Are you using ES 2.0 or an older version?

Comment: Using ES 2.0 on centos 6 64-bit.

Comment: Does it work if you start ES with no security manager: `bin/elasticsearch -Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false`?

Comment: No with that i am getting  "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config" error. In /etc/passwd file i am getting "elasticsearch:x:991:989:elasticsearch user:/home/elasticsearch:/sbin/nologin" and while logging to shell with elasticsearch as user, shell responds with "This account is currently not available."

Comment: Yes, that's because the user has been created with no login capabilities (re: `/sbin/nologin`). Can you make sure that the `elasticsearch` user can access all parent folders in the `/home/hadoop/bigdata/data` hierarchy?

Comment: so should i remove elasticsearch user with all its directories and uninstall-install elasticsearch?

Comment: Not necessarily, but copying folders around can have undesired effects. Just need to understand why this is happening. Usually, it's best to leave the default settings as they are, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah its true to leave default settings. But its also necessary to change settings your way. Since i don't have much space on root i need to go for some other directory..

Comment: Why not copying the folder inside the `/home/elasticsearch/data` folder instead of `/home/hadoop`? The `elasticsearch` user would certainly have access to its own `/home`.

Comment: No directory found : /home/elasticsearch. so should i create it?

Comment: Weird, since that's mentioned in your `passwd` file. It should have been created at the same time as the user was created.

Comment: yes i am also surprised with this behviour.

Comment: so should i create elsticsearch manually and then install elasticsearch again. so it will take user created by me?

Comment: How did you install elasticsearch initially? Using the zip/tarball or with a package manager (yum, rpm)?

Comment: I installed it through yum.

Comment: Something's definitely messed up, so go ahead and try to install again.

Comment: yes thanks for your input and support..

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because of not setting permissions for user "elasticsearch" to access the folder.

Try making "elasticsearch" user(default user of elasticsearch) the owner of the folder using below commands -

```
sudo chown elasticsearch: /home/hadoop/bigdata/data/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ensure that the user **elasticsearch** is the owner and group of the data folder, the user should also have permission (`+x`) to traverse each level of the path to the configured data path (in your case,  `/home/hadoop/bigdata/data/elasticsearch`).

That is, if the parent directory of the Elasticsearch `path.data` is not owned by user **elasticsearch** (as in your case, the parent folder belongs to user **hadoop**)， then you should check each level of the parent directory, to ensure it be set with `o+x` permission (with `chmod`) to guarantee permission to the user `elasticsearch` (*i.e.*, others).

I have learned this solution from other's question: [Elasticsearch cannot open log file: Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501963/elasticsearch-cannot-open-log-file-permission-denied).